# methods missing from scaladoc search

Tags: scala, scaladoc

None of the Value Members of the [Tuple2 class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) appear when I do a search for them.

Examples: [_2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?search=_2), [invert](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?search=invert), [swap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?search=swap)

Are some classes intentionally left out when doing a scaladoc search? Is my browser playing tricks on me?

Comment: Is this not what you see when you search for `_2`? https://i.imgur.com/JbN69Xg.png

Comment: @ChrisMartin; Yes, that's exactly what I see when I search for `_2`. I see the entry for `Product2` but not for `Tuple2`. Likewise, the search for `swap` brings up 6 hits, but none of them from the `Tuple2` class. When I go to the `Tuple2` page I see 2 `val` and 6 `def` entries, but when I search for any of those there is no `Tuple2` listed on the results page.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10385#issuecomment-373665093).

Answer (score 3):

I would guess this is intentional; `Tuple2` inherits `_2` from `Product2` (which does show up in the search results), so perhaps the designers of the search interface thought it would be overly redundant for the search output to include a separate result for every subtype.

You can click on `Product2` and then "Known Subclasses" to find out that `Tuple2` inherits this method.